# Apple Sign In below ios13

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, apple-sign-in

I have a question about Apple Sign In. In App Store Guideline there We can found that Apple Sign in is mandatory when app uses third party sign in options (like google or facebook).As I know Apple sign in mechanism was added in ios 13. What if I want to build app with minimum version of iOS set to 11 or 12? Still I need to implement Apple sign in (and if so, how?)?

Comment: Sign-In with Apple will be visible only if User is running app on iOS 13 and above...else your button will not be visible. I have done the same in one of my projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private func setupLoginWithAppleButton() {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            //Show sign-in with apple button. Create button here via code if you need. 
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            //Hide your sign in with apple button here.
        }
    }
```

---

if you are getting error: Authorization returned an error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.AuthenticationServices.AuthorizationError error 1000.)

> Simply Add "Sign In with Apple" from Capability.

Comment: Did Apple approved this? I know Apple Sign is mandatory for iOS 13, but do they accept to disable it on iOS 12?

Comment: Yes app is live now...I can send you link if you want

Comment: Sign In with Apple added starting from iOS 13

Comment: And one more thing I want to add: I am not disabling the button I am hiding the view

Comment: Well, my implementation is different, but that doesn’t matter, my question was about Apple’s approval of not supporting apple sign in on iOS12, and for that we will see later when the reviewer answers us

Comment: Hey I might be late to the party, but did apple approve the app without iOS12 sign in? @PauloCesar

Comment: SignIn with Apple is mandatory with other social logins from iOS 13 onwards. So no SignIn With Apple in iOS 12. And YES, Apple will approve app.

Comment: @Han Yes, it was approved

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63715205/419348
Apple will approve it if no SignIn With Apple in iOS 12.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to support lower than ios 13 but you can also support lower than ios 13. You can read this guideline 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js/incorporating_sign_in_with_apple_into_other_platforms

first you have to configure your app for redirect url, bottom line is that you have to use the mechanism like you want to provide apple sign in Android, web or other platefrom.

**the best tutorial  I found to configure is:**
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/04/what-the-heck-is-sign-in-with-apple
if you successfully configure then

follow these steps
1-put your button's code in fall back os version.

2-Set apple sign in image on the button you can download button image from here  https://appleid.cdn-apple.com/appleid/button.

3- if you successfully followed tutorial then after clicking sign in button and open this api
https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize?response_type=code&response_mode=form_post&client_id=[your apple sign in client id]&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample-app.com%2Fredirect&state=78536bf485&scope=name+email

in wkwebview or otside the app depending upon you
then you will see screen like this
[image]
enter your credential of apple sign in then if you get success it will redirect to your redirect uri
[image]

Comment: This is inaccurate. The requirement is **not** just for iOS 13. See this answer from an Apple staffer on the Apple Develop Forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/122755.

Comment: @Virendra Gupta Does this API exist now?

Comment: yes this  api exist

Answer (score 0):

As you said Apple sign in mechanism was added in iOS13. If you like to support older versions of iOS you will have to have other sign in method for those users.

In code you check iOS version using `#available` and do your logic around it.

Swift:

```
if #available(iOS 13, *) {
    // Apple sign in code logic
    // Other methods logic
} else {
    // Other methods logic
}
```

Objective C:

```
if (@available(iOS 13, *)) {
    // Apple sign in code logic
    // Other methods logic
} else {
    // Other methods logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the same requirements apply for iOS versions older than iOS 13. An Apple staffer provided this answer on the Apple Developer forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/122755

> For iOS 13 and later, macOS 10.15 and later, tvOS 13 and later, and
> watchOS 6 and later, use the AuthenticationServices framework as
> referenced here.
>
> For iOS 12 and eariler, macOS 10.14 and earlier, tvOS
> 12 and earlier, and watchOS 5 and earlier, as well as web applications
> which cannot directly access Sign in with Apple JS framework, you must
> manually control the sign-in request as referenced here.