# Apple Sign In for iOS 12

Tags: ios, iphone, ios13, ios12

We have users using our application in iOS 10,11,12 and 13 and where we are using third party Sign In like facebook and Google.

Recently it is mandatory to have "Sign in with Apple" if we use the third party sign in . But it seems Apple Signin framework is only supported in iOS 13 .

In this case , whether it is not necessary to support Apple SignIn lower than iOS 13 ?

```
private func setupLoginWithAppleButton() {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            //Show "Sign in with Apple" button and proceed to Apple Sign in 
        } else {
           // Hide "Sign in with Apple" button
        }
    }
```

For Users with iOS version lower than 13 "Sign in with Apple" button wont be displayed and those whose version is 13 and above Apple Sign button will be displayed and proceed with Apple Sign in .

If we submit the application like above does Apple will approve our build ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Apple will approve it. I've made this solution in some apps and it's ok.